# Prove that the inverse image of a closed set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I came across this problem and couldn't make much of a headway.

Let $\overline{p}$ and $\overline{q}$ be two distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}$ such that $$f(x) = (1 - x)\overline{p} + x\overline{q},$$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $E$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Show that the inverse image $f^{-1}(E)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The formula for $f$ doesn't matter, the result is true for any continuous $f$. Continuity is equivalent to inverse images of open sets being open (and hence equivalent to inverse images of closed sets being closed). It seems very weird to me that the problem would ask this very general fact for a particular line. Also, $\bar{p}$ and $\bar{q}$ being distinct is irrelevant (if they're equal $f$ is constant, hence continuous, and the conclusion remains true).

Comment: @IvoTerek True. I think the problem was to be solved by using the limit point definition. This was posed right after the definition of metric spaces and connected sets, compact sets etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of  limits: Suppose a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb R}$ in $\Bbb R$ converges to $x$. Then $f(x_n)=x_n(q-p)+p$ converges to $x(q-p)+p=f(x).$ Because $$0=\|q-p\|\cdot  \lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m\ge n}|x_m-x|=$$ $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m\ge n} (\,\|q-p\|\cdot |x_m-x|\,)=$$  $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m\ge n}\|f(x_m)-f(x)\|.$$

So if every $x_n\in f^{-1}E$ then every $f(x_n)\in E$ so $f(x)\in E$ (because $E$ is closed) so  $x\in f^{-1}E.$